# Unable to find file 'path/NA' when knitting to word_document2 using tbl_summary but works for PDF, HTML etc

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, gtsummary

before you click "next", this is not a path file error.

I am building on a blogpost: https://labrtorian.com/2019/08/26/rmarkdown-template-that-manages-academic-affiliations/

It works well for scientific papers.

My problem is:

In Rmarkdown when calling a data frame I am returned with the error about not being able to find file 'path/NA'

````
    ---
   
    output:
     bookdown::word_document2:
        pandoc_args:
          - --reference-doc=Extras/Reference_Document.docx 
        keep_tex: TRUE

    ---



    ```{r MRE}
    
    library(gtsummary)
    a <- c(10,20,30,40)
    b <- c('book', 'pen', 'textbook', 'pencil_case')
    c <- c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE)
    d <- c(2.5, 8, 10, 7)
    df <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
    
    tbl_summary(df)
    tbl_summary
````

which returns:

> Error: could not find file '/Users/brianbrummer/Documents/Rstudio/Affilitations_template/NA'
> Execution halted

So what gives? I would usually know how to fix a "path not found" error, but not a file...and the file is NA?

files referenced in YAML can be found:

https://github.com/bridaybrummer/author_affiliations_extras.git

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you please update your example to be as minimal as possible (eg remove elements from the yaml that are unrelated to the error). Make the example reproducible, meaning if the error only appears when you reference external files in your yaml, include those files in the post

Comment: @DanielD.Sjoberg Thanks for looking in.

 You can use the link from the blogpost : https://github.com/drdanholmes/Affiliations but you would have to update the 2 lua. files

I am working on getting my repository up and running in the next few minutes and will post another link if you don't get joy with the one above

Comment: Did you make the example is minimal as possible? (ie remove all elements from the yaml that are not required to illustrate your issue)

Comment: it is now as minimal as possible as far as I know @DanielD.Sjoberg

Comment: Thanks I can look tonight likely. So you only get an error when you include the reference doc.in the yaml?

Comment: Exactly, and it only occurs when I use the tbl_summary command. Otherwise I can call the df no problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did some digging and found the issue and a solution. First, if you update your yaml to call the reference document like this, you won't get the error any longer.

```
---
output:
  word_document:
    reference_doc: Reference_Document.docx
---
```

The issue was with the flextable package. If you're looking for community service points, you can post this reprex to their github page to alert them to the issue.

````
---
output:
  word_document:
    pandoc_args:
      - --reference-doc=Reference_Document.docx 
---

```{r MRE}
mtcars |> 
  flextable::flextable()
```
````

Comment: Thanks, this is a workaround however without doing it through Bookdown in my original Rmd, then cross-referencing of tables and fugures doesn't seem to work. I have flagged the issue with flextable on github. Thanks for the contribution.

Comment: Did you try it with bookdown? The code still works...

Comment: The code runs but doesn't retain the format of the reference document.